# Simulating brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, brownian-motion, wiener-measure

I have this BM(Wiener process) which i need to simulate:
[image: BM process]

Where sigma1 = 1

I know that the standard deviation of  B1(t) is sqrt(t), so if we wouldnt have the constant sigma1, the simulation we would have would be: Normal(0: mean, variance: sqrt(t))

But im not sure in general what happens when you have a constant like sigma outside B1?
By that I am wondering, is the simulation going to be: Normal(0: mean, variance: sqrt(t * sigma1) ? or: Normal(0: mean, variance: (sqrt(t) * sqrt(B1)) ? or Normal(0: mean, variance: sqrt(t) * sigma1) ? or something else ?

Comment: If $\mathbb E[|X|^2]<\infty$ then for $c\in\mathbb R$, 
$$
\mathsf{Var}(cX) = c^2\cdot\mathsf{Var}(X).
$$
From there it should be clear what the appropriate variance of the scaled Brownian Motion is.